# How do I move my WAMP local host from firefox to chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, localhost, wamp

I recently installed the WAMP server on my computer and when I open the localhost it automatically opens in firefox.  I want it to open in chrome so I can use the chrome developer tools. How can make my local host open in chrome instead of firefox.  Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 17):

To change the default browser of the **Wamp** server

- Go to the **Wamp** installation directory
- Open **wampmanager.conf** file in a text editor.
- Change the navigator to your browser

  example:- navigator = “C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe”
- save and restart your server

Answer (score 4):

Go to the `wampmanager.conf` and change the navigator to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go in **C Drive**
2. Open **wamp64** folder
3. Open **wampmanager.config** file
4. In last step see **navigator queue** and paste this statement given below

`navigator ="C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"`
or

`"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"`

and close the all folder.

5. Go **wamp server** and  **right click on wamp server**
6. **click on exits option** and **restart the wamp server**
7. **automatically open  localhost in chrome browser** or search **http://localhost** in your browser.