# To change the browser of localhost/phpMyadmin in WAMP

Tags: wamp, wampserver, wamp64

I have installed WAMP. But at the time of installation me selected internet explorer as default browser for opening localhost.Now my browser(internet explorer) is not working properly,so I have to change the browser to google chrome.What are the steps to follow to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

This is an already answered question on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/160730/how-to-change-default-browser-to-open-localhost-in-wampserver) site
By the user: Sonal

and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907686/how-do-i-move-my-wamp-local-host-from-firefox-to-chrome/26751329)
By the user: Buru

I thought it would not work because those answers are from 10 and 5 years ago, but it does.

Just in case, I will use that answer adding some details:

- Open `C:\wamp` or `C:\wamp64` in Windows Explorer (or wherever you
  installed wampserver)
- Open `wampmanager.conf` file in a text editor
- Find the section `[main]`
- Find the following line:

  ```
   navigator = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"
  ```
- Replace it with the location of the desired browser (firefox in this case):

  ```
   navigator = “C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe”
  ```
- Save the the file
- Restart WAMP with right click on the **tray** icon and selecting
  'Refresh'. Then your default browser should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

From wampserver 3.3.0, to set default browser ,you can use wamp setting of GUI like below. Finding the wamp server icon on the right bottom of the screen, and right click it, It will show wamp setting.

[image]